# ajax div reloads with correct data, but with entire webpage within div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that contains a student's schedule, and there is a drop-down box for selecting by semester.

Once they select the semester, there is an ajax post, but when it refreshes, it displays the entire website within that div (with the appropriate schedule for that semester).

It looks like an iframe within a webpage, as seen here: http://cl.ly/Dy3b

Here is the ajax post script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#term').change(function() {

    var form_data = {
      term : $('#term').val(),
      ajax : '1'
    };

    var u = $("#schedulePortletURL").attr("href");

    $.ajax({
      url: u,
      type: 'POST',
      data: form_data,
      success: function(msg) {
        //alert(u);
        $('#view-schedule').html(msg);
      }
    });

    return false;
  });

  });
</script>
```

If possible, could you give me some suggestions of what to investigate to correct this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the call to the server is returning a full HTML page, and your code then puts the full HTML page into the view-schedule div.

To resolve this, create a new HTML page that you can call that contains a html fragment - the chunk that you want to live in the view-schedule div.  Then change schedulePortletURL to point to the new HTML page.

Alternately, you could get the html back (the msg) and parse it to pull out the data you are interested in, then insert the filtered data into the view-schedule div.

Does the existing website have a API at all that you can call?

Comment: As for the api, no. It serves this CodeIgniter app via https://wiki.jasig.org/display/PLT/WebProxy - I call the attr.("href") so the javascript properly rewrites the URL of where the ajax needs to post to. I am new to uPortal, I need to get more access to dig into the other parts of the main page.

Comment: To get a better idea of what's going on, you can use a tool like firebug or Chrome developer tools.  You can then see exactly what POST is being made to the server and exactly what is being returned from the server.  If a redirect of some sort is happening, as David suggests, this would reveal it.

Comment: Brad, I looked into the WebProxy docs, and I would recommend looking at a couple of options they provide:  Clipping Configuration and a Post-Interceptor class.  Both are described at https://wiki.jasig.org/display/PLT/WebProxy+Portlet+Installation+and+Configuration.  To see the interface you need to implement for PostInterceptor, see http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jasig.portlet/WebProxyPortlet/1.1.4/edu/wisc/my/webproxy/beans/interceptors/PostInterceptor.java, and to see how the interceptor class is loaded, see http://bit.ly/xULSQP

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that some kind of error checker in your server-side script is mistakenly firing and causing a redirect to some web page. That web page is then retrieved by the AJAX, then displayed in the DIV. I have had this happen before. You should check your server side script.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have full control over the webpage you are fetching the fetched page should be considered unpure and you should use iframe. Remember that with .html(blob) you will also get javascript code, flash objects etc. which can be used to compromize your users.

If you on the other hand have full control over the fetched webpage (which I assume) you should make a if-statement in your template that checks if the request is ajax-based.:

Pseudo serverside template code:

```
if not request.is_ajax():
    import header.html
import body.html
if not request.is_ajax():
    import footer.html
```